# Symfony config TreeBuilder: invalide type for path

Tags: php, symfony, config

I've been sitting on this problem for quite a while and decided to get help. I have the following TreeBuilder:

```
$treeBuilder->root(0)
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('tab')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('title')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('image')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

And here's the array that I'm trying to validate:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        ["tab"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(18) "Tab title"
          ["image"]=>
          string(7) "img.png"
        }
    }
    [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["tab"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(18) "Tab title"
          ["image"]=>
          string(7) "img.png"
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't validate and always gives me the error `Invalid type for path "0.tab.title". Expected array, but got string`. I'm using version 2.4.3

## LATER EDIT

Ok, I changed the structure of my array and now it looks like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["tab"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(4) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(18) "Gogoși cu zmoală"
          ["image"]=>
          string(7) "img.png"
          ["target_view_type"]=>
          string(1) "t"
          ["data"]=>
          string(9) "test data"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(4) {
          ["title"]=>
          string(18) "Gogoși cu zmoală"
          ["image"]=>
          string(7) "img.png"
          ["target_view_type"]=>
          string(1) "t"
          ["data"]=>
          string(9) "test data"
        }
    }
}
```

And the TreeBuilder looks like this:

```
$treeBuilder->root(0)
->children()
    ->arrayNode('0')
        ->prototype('array')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('title')->end()
                ->scalarNode('image')->end()
                ->scalarNode('target_view_type')->end()
                ->scalarNode('data')->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();
```

And here's the error i'm getting: `Invalid type for path "0.0.title". Expected array, but got string`

Comment: I've made some modifications, I added prototype to the root node. But now the error is `Unrecognized options "title, image" under "0.tab"`

Comment: how do you validate? can you post this?

Comment: @ivoba I just pass that array to the Processor. It should have this structure `array[0]->array['tab']->array['title]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
->arrayNode('tab')
  ->prototype('array')
    ->children()
      ->scalarNode('title')->end()
      ->scalarNode('image')->end()
    ->end()
  ->end()
->end()
```

in the config.yml it would be like this:

```
tab:
  - title: foo
    image: bar
  - title: boo
    image: har
```

this will validate against:

```
'tab' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'title' => string 'foo' (length=3)
          'image' => string 'bar' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'title' => string 'boo' (length=3)
          'image' => string 'har' (length=3)
```

This is a bit different to your approach but you will achieve the same i guess.

Comment: Yes, I just made those change right before you post it. It gives me this error: `Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "0"`. "0" refers to my  root node.

Comment: can you post your config.yml part?

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem. I'm not using YAML, that var_dump-ed array was exactly what I passed to Processor->processConfiguration(). The problem was that I had to pass it an array of my final config, like this: `(new Processor())->processConfiguration($response, [$response->elements->varsToArray()])`